# Process to Import specific text in excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import many tables into excel (with fixed width option selected) and I would like it to paste it to certain areas as a function of "i", see below:
`For i = 0 to X`

I would like "X" to be the number of tables that are imported from the text file, I think the Count function can be used here but I'm not sure how

So far I have this code written up, but I'm not sure what the syntax is for the commends I posted after some of the commands:

```vb
Sub ImportLPileTextFile()
    Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, pos1 As Integer, pos2 As Integer

    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
        
    Open myFile For Input As #1
        
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        text = text & textline
    Loop
    Close #1
        
    pos1 = InStr(text, "   y, inches ")
    pos2 = InStr(text, "000         ") 'I'm using the zero values after the decimal becuase the end text is sometimes different
                                       'can I set this second condition to be "if two blank lines appear" somehow?
                                       'There are a minimum of 2 open spaces after the table ends. See photo

     For i = 0 To 'Count(how many items are pasted)
     
         Range(.Cells(8, 3 * i + 1)).Value = Mid(text, pos1 + 0, 0) ' is 0 right? I want to include this in what I want copied, see photo example
         'How do i paste this table as a special paste with "Fixed width" option?
                
     Next i
End Sub
```

I know the `i = 0 to ...` loop is not in the right area, it needs to be before `Loop` for `Do Until` ? Right?

Below are two images:

1. Of what the file would look like after it's pasted into my `ActiveSheet`.
   I've placed notes in the image to show the purpose of my `i = 0 to ...` function. Note the "paste data below..." is where I'd like the data pasted.
   [image: Where the data will be pasted]
2. The actual text file and the exact data I need to pull from:

[image: Text file where I'll extract information]

3. Word version of the text file with the paragraph option showing all indentations per the request of Tim. Left shows how the first table will always look, the second is how the second and remaining tables will look. Worst case scenario, they'll all always have "y,inches p,lbs.in" above them, so I can always use that as the first string to look for, I don't necessarily have to have those in my excel, I can manually input them and have the actual numbers be the data that's copied.

[image: Word Version showing indentation in paragraph mode]

When I copy from the text file and paste special into excel with "Fixed Width" option, then it pastes perfectly with the two columns as shown in my excel image above.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this and giving me advice and direction.

Comment: Would be helpful to open your text file in Word, then turn on "Show paragraphs and other hidden formatting symbols, and include that screenshot, so we can better see what's in that file.

Comment: I'll add that in @TimWilliams, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @TimWilliams I've added the requested screenshot, and a note 3 which may help narrow down what I can use in the ```inStr()``` command. the problem is that at the end of the data (whether it's 18 rows or 20 rows of data) the text is not the same. However, there will always be at least one blank line or space, however you say it. I think that the second ```inStr()``` should somehow pick up the "the first blank line occurring after "y,inches p, lbs.in" if that's possible.

Comment: Can you share an actual file for testing?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've uploaded it to google drive, I couldn't see a way to upload it on here. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qB5a8XxdKAIWSMcDHHAkWDlrSKnR23fn?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me - you may need to tweak it a bit to get everything to go where you want.

```vb
Sub ImportLPileTextFile()
    Dim colTables As Collection, tbl As Collection, cDest As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rw, n As Long, fName As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet        'or whatever
    Set cDest = ws.Range("A8")  'tables start here
    
    fName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If Len(fName) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set colTables = GetFileData(fName) 'read the file
    Debug.Print "Found " & colTables.Count & " tables"
    
    For Each tbl In colTables
        n = 0
        'write the header
        cDest.Resize(1, 2).Value = Array("y, inches", "p, lbs/in")
        For Each rw In tbl                           'loop all rows
            n = n + 1                                'next output line down
            cDest.Offset(n).Resize(1, 2).Value = rw  'write a row
        Next rw
        Set cDest = cDest.Offset(0, 3) 'next table output start cell
    Next tbl
End Sub

'Given a file path, return a collection of collections, where each contained
'  collection rpresents one table, and is a set of arrays of (yvalue, p value)
'  representing "rows" in that table
Function GetFileData(fPath As String)
    Dim colTables As New Collection, fso As Object, f As Object, txt
    Dim inTable As Boolean, tbl As Collection, iBlank As Long, y, p
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set f = fso.opentextfile(fPath, 1) 'for reading
    Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
        txt = f.readline()
        iBlank = IIf(Len(txt) = 0, iBlank + 1, 0) 'counting consecutive blank lines
        
        'start of a table?
        If txt Like "*y, inches*p, lbs/in*" Then
            Set tbl = New Collection  'start a new collection for rows
            inTable = True            'set flag
        Else
            If inTable Then
                If Len(txt) > 20 Then  'have some data?
                    'skip the "------" header
                    If Not txt Like "*----*" Then
                        y = Trim(Left(txt, 14))
                        p = Trim(Mid(txt, 15))
                        'if y and p are numeric then add as a "line"
                        If IsNumeric(y) And IsNumeric(p) Then
                            tbl.Add Array(CDbl(y), CDbl(p))
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    If iBlank >= 2 Then
                        'done with this table
                        inTable = False    'reset flag
                        colTables.Add tbl  'add this table to the return collection
                    End If 'two consecutive blank lines
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetFileData = colTables
End Function
```

Comment: Oh my gosh this worked for me too, perfectly. I'm going to study the code to understand each function and it's place. I have so much gratitude for your effort my friend, thank you. I appreciate all the explanation comments you wrote down as well. If there's someplace you would recommend I start to study to understand how you fit this code together beside learning each functions purpose and using them individually, please let me know. Thank you again Tim!

Comment: Parsing data from text files is often a bit tricky and I'm never confident I caught all of the "edge cases" (eg this will likely miss the last table if your file ends suddenly in the middle of that table).  As for logic you just need to figure out how you'd do it manually then try to translate that to code.

Comment: That scenario wouldn't occur for these output files so I'm confident it'll capture all the tables. My goal is to now reverse engineer your code to understand its place in the manual process.